# Total width on Focus Blog theme (WordPress)

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to increase the total width of the text container to 95%, whatever the resolution is, for my blog

https://osezrealiservosreves.com/

So I wrote the following code (for mobile)

But it does not work
It applies margin-left correctly but the width of the container doesn't increase.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .wrp {
    margin: 0 2.5% !important;
    width: 95% !important;
  }
}
```

[image]

I have quite the same issue on desktop mode,

I want to increase the width of the blog flux in home page.

The defaults settings are

```
.cnt .bSe.left, .cnt .bSe.right {
    width: 67.59%;
}
.cnt .sAs {
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: 30.55%;
}
```

So it's already 100% basically, but it does not cover all the width for my resolution

[image]

I would like to do something that looks more to this website that uses the same theme, but I can't find how he did: https://traficmania.com/lire-le-blog/

[image]

You have any idea what prevents it to work?

I'm pretty sure it's quite easy but I might have missed something

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance :)

Pascal

Comment: Have you tried using Bootstrap? or Foundation?

Comment: Your margins and certainly getting applied, and it's likely your `width` is as well (given your `!important` declaration).  Remember, `width` is relative to the direct parent. I can only assume you have a *parent* that is not wide enough. Be careful of specificity as well. In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your **existing code** and details any failed [**attempts made so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the **question itself**.

Comment: Hello, no I haven't used Bootstrap or Foundation. I'm really fine with my theme design, I just need to adapt a few elements :)

Comment: to Obsidian Age, yeah I guess I do not write with the specific selector, so here lies the mistake, but I definitely can't find it. 

I'm sorry I was not clear enough to you, I've rewritten it in the best way I could, with specifying my own code and the default code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to style elements within the wrapper, that element should be set to :
width: 100%.
So 100% of the wrapper will be taken.
Leave the wrp width on 95% and inside on 100% and it should work.

Comment: Nop it doesn't unfortunately, whether for the blog page or for the home page. I just can't see any  CSS differences between my blog and Trafic Mania, I think he used a html {zoom: 125%;} property